# Image slideshow timer speed getting increased when we click on next or previous buttons, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image, slider

I have written simple image slider using JavaScript. In that I have set 5000 ms timer to slide automatically. but it is getting increased when we click on next or previous button. I have pasted the code below

HTML Code:

```
    <section id="intro">
        <div id="prev"><br/><br/><br/><br/><img onclick="rotateImages(0);" src="./images/slider/prev1.png"/></div>
        <div id="next"><img onclick="rotateImages(1);" src="./images/slider/next1.png"/></div>
    </section>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var num = 0;
        var temp = 0;
        var speed = 5000;
        var preloads = [];

        preload(
                '1.png',
                '2.jpg',
                '3.jpg',
                '4.jpg',
                '5.png'
                );

        function preload() {

            for (var c = 0; c < arguments.length; c++) {
                preloads[preloads.length] = new Image();
                preloads[preloads.length - 1].src = arguments[c];
            }
        }

        function rotateImages(flag) {
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                num = num - 1;
                if (num < 0)
                    num = preloads.length;
            }
            else
            {
                num = num + 1;
                if (num >= preloads.length)
                    num = 0;
            }
            if (num == temp) {
                rotateImages(1);
            } else {
                var str = preloads[num].src;
                var resArr = str.split("/");
                var picName = resArr[resArr.length - 1];
                document.getElementById("intro").style.backgroundImage = 'url(./images/slider/' + picName + ')';
                temp = num;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    rotateImages(1)
                }, speed);
            }
        }

        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    rotateImages(1)
                }, speed)
            }, false);
        } else {
            if (window.attachEvent) {
                window.attachEvent('onload', function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        rotateImages(1)
                    }, speed)
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: You probably just need to stop the spinnign before adding `speed`to it. Since you add speed every time you call your function.

Comment: You should clear the old setTimeout.. or use setInterval instead

Comment: Thanks @Baldráni
where i should stop the spinning.. can you please paste the respected line of code with modifications..

Comment: Thank you.. 'setInterval' method solved my problem :)
@AhmadSantarissy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the previous timer. Otherwise there will be new timers added with every call to rotateImages(), Save the reference returned from setTimeout() and then use clearTimeout() to clear the timer if it's set

```
var num = 0;
var temp = 0;
var speed = 5000;
var preloads = [];
var timeout;

preload(
  '1.png',
  '2.jpg',
  '3.jpg',
  '4.jpg',
  '5.png'
);

function preload() {

  for (var c = 0; c < arguments.length; c++) {
    preloads[preloads.length] = new Image();
    preloads[preloads.length - 1].src = arguments[c];
  }
}

function rotateImages(flag) {
  if (flag == 0) {
    num = num - 1;
    if (num < 0)
      num = preloads.length;
  } else {
    num = num + 1;
    if (num >= preloads.length)
      num = 0;
  }
  if (num == temp) {
    rotateImages(1);
  } else {
    var str = preloads[num].src;
    var resArr = str.split("/");
    var picName = resArr[resArr.length - 1];
    document.getElementById("intro").style.backgroundImage = 'url(./images/slider/' + picName + ')';
    temp = num;

    if (!!timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      rotateImages(1);
    }, speed);
  }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      rotateImages(1)
    }, speed)
  }, false);
} else {
  if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        rotateImages(1)
      }, speed)
    });
  }
}
```